# TypeError: RulesButton.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, pycord

I'm getting this Error:
`TypeError: RulesButton.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

I'm trying to create an Button that grants a Role upon Interacting in PyCord.

Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ui import *
from discord.ext.commands import Cog
from botconfig.rules import *
from botconfig.phrases import *

class RulesButton(discord.ui.Button):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            label="Accept the Rules here!",
            style=discord.enums.ButtonStyle.green,
            custom_id="interaction:RoleButton",
        )
    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        user = interaction.user

        role = interaction.guild.get_role(rules_id)

        if role is None:
            return

        if role not in user.roles:
            await user.add_roles(role)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f" You accepted the Rules!", ephemeral=True)

        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"❌ You already accepted the Rules!", ephemeral=True)

class Rules(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.is_owner()
    @commands.command()
    async def rules(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        if isinstance(ctx.channel, discord.DMChannel):
            return# Command
        view = discord.ui.View(timeout=None)
        view.add_item(RulesButton(self.bot))
        await ctx.send(f"{RULES_BILD_URL}")
        await ctx.send(f"{RULES_BESCHREIBUNG}", view=view)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        self.bot.add_view(RulesButton(self))

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Rules(bot))
```

Adding:
`self.bot.add_view(RulesButton(self))` at any point and in any Class / Subclass results in:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Benja\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 382, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Benja\Documents\HOLYBot V3\HOLYBot-V3\cogs\rules.py", line 36, in on_ready
    self.bot.add_view(RulesButton(self))
TypeError: RulesButton.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Without passing self:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Benja\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 382, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Benja\Documents\HOLYBot V3\HOLYBot-V3\cogs\rules.py", line 36, in on_ready
    self.bot.add_view(RulesButton())
  File "C:\Users\Benja\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 1735, in add_view
    raise TypeError(f"expected an instance of View not {view.__class__!r}")
TypeError: expected an instance of View not <class 'cogs.rules.RulesButton'>
```

I'm completly lost on what to do, been trying out stuff for hours now.

Comment: why would you pass a parameter to `RulesButton`?

Comment: @njzk2 - I just switched from JS to PY, In my Cog the Ticketsystem i needed to pass self, bot as im completely accessing these with the callback Function. Now, these were my Troubleshooting steps which im trying to look forward to learn more about it.

Comment: "im completely accessing these with the callback Function", hum, no you're not?

Comment: @njzk2 Not talking about this RulesButton here, Talking about the Same i did with the Ticket System as the Whole Interaction is Within that Class.

Comment: what ticket system? I think you may just need to wrap your button in a view, same as you do in the `rules` function

Comment: @njzk2 I'll update my Post at the Buttom with the Class of the Ticketsystem where im Passing the Parameters.

Comment: that's way too much code. Please reduce that to a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You should create a view class. Not a button class. This example is straight from pycord.

```py
class View(discord.ui.View): # Create a class called View that subclasses discord.ui.View
    @discord.ui.button(label="Click me!", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, emoji="") # Create a button with the label " Click me!" with color Blurple
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("You clicked the button!") # Send a message when the button is clicked

@bot.slash_command() # Create a slash command
async def button(ctx):
    await ctx.respond("This is a button!", view=View()) # Send a message with our View class that contains the button
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you! I've seen this from pycord aswell, but it has not solved my Problem in any way as it still we're serving Problems Deploying. Thank you so much for your Suggestion tho!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workarround.

Button Class:

```
class RoleButton(discord.ui.Button):
    def __init__(self, role: discord.Role):
        """A button for one role. `custom_id` is needed for persistent views."""
        super().__init__(
            label="Accept the Rules",
            emoji="✅",
            style=discord.ButtonStyle.green,
            custom_id=str(rules_id),
        )
```

Passing the following into the Cog Class:

```
        view = discord.ui.View(timeout=None)
        view.add_item(RoleButton(rules_id))
```

aswell as passing folling into on_ready Event

```
        view = discord.ui.View(timeout=None)
        view.add_item(RoleButton(rules_id))
```

Thanks for your Suggestions! <3